# Source for dividing the ten commandments into Ben Adam Lamakom and Ben Adam Lechavero

Tags: sources-mekorot, pentateuch-chumash, aseres-hadibros, bein-adam-lachavero, bein-adam-lamakom

This is something that I have heard and been taught many times, but I can't find it sourced anywhere. I do see this concept quoted often in various articles (via Google searches). The question on this division would be why is Kibud Av categorized as Ben Adam Lamakom.

Comment: Does the mishna in Yuma 85b seem to be what you're looking for?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28413/170

Comment: @msh210 I fail to see how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Ramban to Exodus 20:13-14](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Exodus.20.13.1)  says this idea. I'm not sure if he is the first.

> והנה עשרת הדברות חמשה בכבוד הבורא וחמשה לטובת האדם, כי כבד את אביך כבוד האל, כי לכבוד הבורא צוה לכבד האב המשתתף ביצירה, ונשארו חמשה לאדם בצרכו וטובתו.
>
> And behold, the Ten Statements (Commandments) are five for the glory of the Creator and five for the benefit of man - as Honor your father and your mother is [for] the glory of God, as for the glory of the Creator did He command to honor the father that participated in the formation [of the child]. And five remain for man - for his needs and for his benefits.

You see he addresses your last point, that honoring one’s father and mother is considered honoring Hashem (see [Kiddushin 30b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.30b.18)).

See also [Beis Elokim Sha’ar HaYesodos Chapter 12](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14113&st=&pgnum=107).